# Присвоить полям объекта массивы списков и отправить его в виде JSON

Tags: php, json

Здравствуйте люди добрые!
Встала нужда сделать на стороне сервера выборку из каталогов, чтобы получить список изображений и отправить его по запросу в виде JSON, чтобы далее уже трепать его всеми правдами и неправдами в браузерах пользователей.

$rootsDir - это корневой каталог, где лежат прочие папки с изображениями, которые и требуется обойти.

```
<?php
$rootsDir = '../img/mc/pvpe/classes/';
$classes = GetMyDir($rootsDir); $classCount = count($classes);

for ($i = 2; $i < $classCount; $i++)
    $arr[$classes[$i]] = GetMyDir($rootsDir . $classes[$i]);
print_r($arr);
echo json_encode($arr);

function GetMyDir($path) {
    return scandir($path);
}
?>
```

В результате, требуется получить строку вида:

```
{"nameFolder1":["image_01.png","image_02.png",...],"nameFolder2":["image_01.png","image_02.png",...]}
```

print_r() - как раз демонстрирует результат, который и ожидается, а вот идущий за ним json_encode() - ничего не возвращает.

UPD: Нашёл причину - кириллица в имени файлов. Есть ли возможность использования русских имён для файлов? Это критично, потому как требуется для сокращения писанины, использовать их имена в работе. Файлов много и именно поэтому возникла необходимость иметь и на сейчас и на будущее инструмент, для подобных ситуаций.

Answer (score 0):

Прошу прощения, лекарство было найдено тут же, в исследовании нескольких статей на "Стаке". Вкладки уже закрыл, так что ограничусь решением, может кому-то так же поможет:

```
<?php
$rootsDir = '../img/mc/pvpe/classes/';
$classes = GetMyDir($rootsDir); $classCount = count($classes);

for ($i = 2; $i < $classCount; $i++) {
    $arrAllNames = GetMyDir($rootsDir . $classes[$i]); $namesCount = count($arrAllNames);
    for ($j = 2; $j < $namesCount; $j++)
        $arrNames[] = iconv('windows-1251', 'UTF-8',$arrAllNames[$j]);
    $arr[$classes[$i]] = $arrNames;
}
echo json_encode($arr,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

function GetMyDir($path) {
    return scandir($path,SCANDIR_SORT_NONE);
}
?>
```

Здесь ключевую роль играет функция iconv(), которой, проходясь по элементам массива перекодируем значения хранящихся в них строк. Ну и конечно же опция "JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE", чтобы получать не коды символов Юникода, а уже преобразованную строку.
Спасибо всем, кто оставил ориентиры своей мудрости на страницах этой площадки!

Comment: У вас фаил php в какой кодировке? И скобочки у `{}` не забывайте раставлять.